# Acing or A'cing, and why?

Tags: orthography

I see people using the term 'acing' when earning a perfect score on a test. For example:

> "I aced my math test."

or

> "I'm so acing this test."

Are the ways expressed above proper?

If so, why isn't this term expressed as *A-ced*, *A-cing*, *A'cing*, or *A'ced* for the letter grade?

Comment: What does your favorite dictionary say? -- The cheapo one on my computer has the example *"I* ***aced*** *my grammar test."*

Comment: Could you not mix the word Ace with the colloquial use of "A"?

Comment: @BlessedGeek The question has been edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the meaning of *ace a test* is to get the highest grade (A), the word *ace* itself is not an expansion of the letter A. Rather it gets its meaning from being first, of highest value, or superlative in some way.